# Proof/disproof $M_1 \subset M_2, M_2 \subset M_1$ or $M_1 = M_2$ for $M_1 = \overline{A} \cap \overline{B} \text{ and } M_2= \overline{(A {\cap}B)}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, proof-writing

Given are the sets $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

I want to know if $M_1 \subset M_2, M_2 \subset M_1$ or $M_1 = M_2$ can be proven/disproven for this case:

$$M_1 = \overline{A} \cap \overline{B} \text{ and } M_2= \overline{(A {\cap}B)}$$

I think

$$\overline{A \cup B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$$

,which is why the opposite should also be true, so

$M_1 \subset M_2$

$M_2 \subsetneq M_2$

$M_1 \neq M_2$

I have a bit trouble understanding closures, so I don't know if this is true

Comment: The inequalities that always hold are $\overline A\cap\overline B\supseteq \overline{A\cap B}$ and $\overline A\cup\overline B=\overline{A\cup B}$. They cannot be improved in this generality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$ is closed and contains $A \cap B$, so

$$\overline{A \cap B} \subseteq \overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$$

and this cannot be improved: take $\Bbb R$ usual topology, $A=\Bbb Q$, $B=\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$ then $A \cap B=\emptyset=\overline{A \cap B}$ while
$\overline{A} = \overline{B} = \Bbb R$ and so $\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}=\Bbb R$, a maximal difference...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you also tell me what it would be like if $M_1 = \partial A \cap \partial B$ and $M_2 = \partial(A \cap B)$?

Comment: @JavaTeachMe2018 do the same example..